# WPF TreeView with right alignment values

Tags: wpf, treeview, alignment

I have a problem with my wpf treeview. It's code goes like this:

```
<TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Items}" Grid.RowSpan="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
        <TreeView.Resources>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type m:MyTreeItem}" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
                <DockPanel LastChildFill="True">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Value}" DockPanel.Dock="Right"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Display}" DockPanel.Dock="Left"/>
                </DockPanel>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
        </TreeView.Resources>
    </TreeView>
```

Where MyTreeItem is a simple class with 2 String properties (Display and Value) and a List of MyTreeItem called Items.

I need the tree view to display all 'Values' aligned to the right, while maintaining the tree tabulation of the items 'Display', based on it's deepth.

I have tryed to set the dockPanel to a fixed width, but that didn't work.

I want to do this without any c# code, just xaml.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly you want to Stretch the `TreeViewItem`s and align `Value` to the right. To get the `TreeViewItem`s to Stretch Horizontaly you'll need to edit the Template for `TreeViewItem`. The problem is explained here: http://leecampbell.blogspot.com/2009/01/horizontal-stretch-on-treeviewitems.html

Here is an edited version of the `TreeViewItem` which does this. Note that you'll have to add a reference to **PresentationFramework.Aero** for this to work

*Sample*
[image]

```
<TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Items}"
            Grid.RowSpan="2"
            Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
            ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource StretchTreeViewItemStyle}">
    <TreeView.Resources>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type m:MyTreeItem}" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
            <DockPanel LastChildFill="True">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Value}" DockPanel.Dock="Right"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Display}" DockPanel.Dock="Left"/>
            </DockPanel>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </TreeView.Resources>
</TreeView>
```

**StretchTreeViewItemStyle**

```
<Style x:Key="TreeViewItemFocusVisual">
    <Setter Property="Control.Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <Rectangle/>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
<PathGeometry x:Key="TreeArrow" Figures="M0,0 L0,6 L6,0 z"/>
<Style x:Key="ExpandCollapseToggleStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
    <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="False"/>
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="16"/>
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="16"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
                <Border Background="Transparent" Height="16" Padding="5,5,5,5" Width="16">
                    <Path x:Name="ExpandPath" Data="{StaticResource TreeArrow}" Fill="Transparent" Stroke="#FF989898">
                        <Path.RenderTransform>
                            <RotateTransform Angle="135" CenterY="3" CenterX="3"/>
                        </Path.RenderTransform>
                    </Path>
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="ExpandPath" Value="#FF1BBBFA"/>
                        <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="ExpandPath" Value="Transparent"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="RenderTransform" TargetName="ExpandPath">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <RotateTransform Angle="180" CenterY="3" CenterX="3"/>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                        <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="ExpandPath" Value="#FF595959"/>
                        <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="ExpandPath" Value="#FF262626"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
<Style x:Key="StretchTreeViewItemStyle"
    TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}"
    xmlns:Microsoft_Windows_Themes="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Windows.Themes;assembly=PresentationFramework.Aero">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="{Binding VerticalContentAlignment, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}}"/>
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="1,0,0,0"/>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}"/>
    <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{StaticResource TreeViewItemFocusVisual}"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition MinWidth="19" Width="Auto"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        <RowDefinition/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <ToggleButton x:Name="Expander" ClickMode="Press" IsChecked="{Binding IsExpanded, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" Style="{StaticResource ExpandCollapseToggleStyle}"/>
                    <Border x:Name="Bd" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Grid.Column="1" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                        <ContentPresenter x:Name="PART_Header" ContentSource="Header" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
                    </Border>
                    <ItemsPresenter x:Name="ItemsHost" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1"/>
                </Grid>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsExpanded" Value="false">
                        <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="ItemsHost" Value="Collapsed"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="HasItems" Value="false">
                        <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="Expander" Value="Hidden"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Bd" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}}"/>
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightTextBrushKey}}"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <MultiTrigger>
                        <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="true"/>
                            <Condition Property="IsSelectionActive" Value="false"/>
                        </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Bd" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}}"/>
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}"/>
                    </MultiTrigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}}"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing" Value="true">
            <Setter Property="ItemsPanel">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <VirtualizingStackPanel/>
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Comment: the link is dead

Answer (score 0):

```
class StretchedTreeView : TreeView {
    protected override void OnItemContainerStyleChanged(Style oldItemContainerStyle, Style newItemContainerStyle) {
        base.OnItemContainerStyleChanged(oldItemContainerStyle, newItemContainerStyle);
        newItemContainerStyle.Setters
            .Add(new EventSetter(LoadedEvent, new RoutedEventHandler(TreeViewItem_Loaded)));
    }
    void TreeViewItem_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
        TreeViewItem item = sender as TreeViewItem;
        if (item == null) {
            return;
        }
        ContentPresenter cp = FindVisualChild<ContentPresenter>(item);
        cp.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Stretch;
        Border border = FindVisualChild<Border>(item, "Bd");
        border.SetValue(Grid.ColumnSpanProperty, 2);
    }
    static T FindVisualChild<T>(DependencyObject obj, string name = null) where T : DependencyObject {
        for (int i = 0 ; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(obj) ; i++) {
            DependencyObject child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(obj, i);
            if (child != null && child is T
                && (name == null || !(child is FrameworkElement) || name == ((FrameworkElement) child).Name)) {
                return (T) child;
            }
            else {
                T childOfChild = FindVisualChild<T>(child, name);
                if (childOfChild != null) {
                    return childOfChild;
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

*For anyone else:*

[see this](https://wpf.2000things.com/2017/09/23/1218-stretching-items-in-treeview-across-entire-control/)

[image: Values aligned to right]

which uses a treeview but
requires modification of the *ItemContainerStyle* and *HorizontalContentAlignment*, e.g

```
<TreeView Grid.Row="0" Margin="5" 
          ItemsSource="{Binding Breeds}" 
          ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource TreeViewItemStyle1}" 
          HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch">
```

[or this](https://www.codeproject.com/articles/24973/treelistview-2)

[image: Multiple Values aligned to the right]

which requires a using a new control type, *TreeListView*, e.g

```
    <local:TreeListView AllowsColumnReorder="True">
      <local:TreeListView.ItemTemplate>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Children}" />
      </local:TreeListView.ItemTemplate>
      <local:TreeListView.Columns>       
        <GridViewColumn Header="Name" Width="200">
            <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">                         
                        <local:TreeListViewExpander/>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
        </GridViewColumn>
        ...
```

Comment: Also maybe useful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61217523/wpf-treeview-how-to-make-controls-align-relative-to-every-treeviewitem-yet-sti/61241235#61241235