# How to align the values in the Tree view wpf

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a tree view and the tree view has two databound values Name and value.
I am binding through hirearchial data template. The output looks like this.

```
India-5
     AP-2
      sec -2
     Up -3
       Mp -3
```

But the output should be like this all the numbers should start from same position(i.e all numbers should from the last value)
instead of tree like structure

```
                             India      5
                                AP      2
                                  sec   2
                                Up      3
                                  Mp    3
```

Any Ideas or solutions appreciated. Tried placing in grids, Hirearchial templates but could not achieve

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution for this. This can be achieved by overriding your treeview item style
You can refer this link  [WPF TreeView with right alignment values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4969418/wpf-treeview-with-right-alignment-values)

This link has code sample.